# google geocoding xml to SQLms

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, google-geocoding-api

i use google API

simple class

```
    public static string result;
        static async Task adres(string gps)
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();
            result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?location_type=rooftop&latlng=" + gps+"&key=APIKEY);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
            //return result;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            adres("@lat, @lng");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

that what i'm trying to do is insert data from that API to my SQL table
i was looking for something like that but can't find what i need.
result from API look like this

```
     {
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "6201",
                   "short_name" : "6201",
                   "types" : [ "street_number" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "South Pierce Street",
                   "short_name" : "S Pierce St",
                   "types" : [ "route" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Littleton",
                   "short_name" : "Littleton",
                   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Jefferson County",
                   "short_name" : "Jefferson County",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Colorado",
                   "short_name" : "CO",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Stany Zjednoczone",
                   "short_name" : "US",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "80123",
                   "short_name" : "80123",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "6201 S Pierce St, Littleton, CO 80123, Stany Zjednoczone",
             "geometry" : {
                "location" : {
                   "lat" : 39.6038386,
                   "lng" : -105.0742384
                },
                "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : 39.60518758029149,
                      "lng" : -105.0728894197085
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : 39.6024896197085,
                      "lng" : -105.0755873802915
                   }
                }
             },
             "place_id" : "ChIJM5UH7FR-a4cRepjc9kKSsd8",
             "types" : [ "street_address" ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }


AND MY QUERY

INSERT iNTO GPS
VALUES
(@record_id, @GPS, @full, @street_number, @route, @political, @locality, @administrative_area, @county, @postal_code, @place_id, 1)
```

please help

Comment: This is not XML but JSON... Please clearify and re-tag...

Comment: You are right i copy wrong side, i will correct that when i got PC